# code opens all submenus on clicking primary menu li item

Tags: jquery, html

The PHP code generates a navigation menu of this structure -

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="link">LINK 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 2</a>     <!-- click disabled -->  
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">LINK 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">LINK 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 6</a>     <!-- click disabled -->
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="link">LINK 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">LINK 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="link">LINK 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="link">LINK 11</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of having to open `sub-menu` using `hover`, I want to make it open using `click`
The jQuery for `click` is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var li = $('.menu>li',this).has('.sub-menu');
    $('>a',li).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.sub-menu',li).toggle();
    });
});
```

The only problem is that while clicking, all the `ul` with class `.sub-menu` gets opened. I only want the `sub-menu` of the currently clicked anchor tag to open. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/cjvwkvq9/

```
$("li > a")
    .on("click", function (e) {
    $(e.target).next().toggle();
});
```

Where `$(e.target)` is the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `this` keyword? Inside the click handler, try replacing `'.sub-menu',li` with `this`.
For more information about this visit: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient code in this case would be to have a single handler on the `<ul>` rather than attaching event listeners to all `<li>`.

```
$('ul.menu').on('click', 'li', function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    ...and so on ...
});
```